# How to get iOS language + region codes

Tags: ios

I can retrieve all language codes like so:

```
Locale.isoLanguageCodes
```

And all region codes:

```
Locale.isoRegionCodes
```

But I would like a list of all language ID's.  There is a short example list described in the [Apple Language and Locale IDs reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html)

> en-AU for English as used in Australia
>
> en-GB for English as used in United Kingdom
>
> fr-FR for French as used in France
>
> fr-CA for French as used in Canada
>
> de-AT for German as used in Austria
>
> de-CH for German as used in Switzerland

I'm hoping there's some standard list so I wouldn't list all possible permutations of Language + Region.  Then I'll get combinations like, Italian as used in Mongolia.  Anyone know of a source or method to produce a standard list of language ID's?

**Bonus Question** - Does anyone know how to get a list of the full spelling of the languages or regions and not just the code?

Comment: Are you looking for `Locale.availableIdentifiers`?

Comment: @rmaddy Yep that's it.  Thanks.  And from that I can get the full name using `func localizedString(forIdentifier: String)`